# NTLM/Windows Authentication and GetAllUsers()

Tags: asp.net, membership, single-sign-on, provider

I'm designing a web app which will be used on an intranet so Windows authentication mode is ideal.  However, part of the app would need the ability to get a list of users (to pick users for assignments.  Membership.GetAllUsers() doesn't apply (on its own) with windows-authentication.  I can't use ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider because I won't be allowed to store credentials to bind with; so any AD access would have to be done as the authenticated user.

I've searched off and on for weeks for a clear cut example or solution to this, and I'm beginning to think that nobody in the world has this same problem.

Is my only option to use Application_AuthenticateRequest and connect the two worlds of "membership" to "windows auth"?  But then how do I get a list of "all" users elsewhere in the app?  Is there an ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider which impersonates as the calling user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD can contain a very large number of users - so in the general case it's not usually practical to list all users.

If you're designing a UI to pick users (e.g. for assignment to roles) I'd do something similar to the existing Windows UI's to select an AD User or Group.  For example, enter a few characters and search for matches by first name, last name or common name.  Display all matches (up to some maximum - say 1000) and let the user pick from these.

Comment: So I'll be rolling my own, huh? I did plan on limiting the AD "All Users" to a definable subtree or filter.

Comment: "So I'll be rolling my own, huh" - I guess so, unless you can find an implementation somewhere.  I had a look at Sharepoint, which has a UI for assigning permissions to AD users, but it's an ugly implementation that uses an ActiveX control (Microsoft AddressBook or something).